# String Class C++ Why the reversed string is not build correctly?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, class

I have to check if a string is palindrome. I'm new to C++ and I really can't understand why my code is not working..

```
 bool isPalindrome(string str) 
    {
        string str2;
        int length = str.length();
        for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            str2[i] = str[length - 1 - i];
        
        if(str == str2)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `str2[i] = str[length - 1 - i];` --> `str2.at(i) = str[length - 1 - i];` -- Then you should be able to understand why your code doesn't work.

Comment: `return std::equal( str.begin(), str.end(), str.rbegin() );`

Comment: One of the least helpful descriptions of a problem is "not working". Should I draw the conclusion that instead of checking if your string is a palindrome, your program used the string to crack a top secret computer and now the authorities are on your trail? How exactly does your code not work? *Maybe think in terms of the next person with the same problem; how can you describe your issue so that someone else can recognize that they have the same issue?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cpp
string str2;
```

This creates a string object that is empty.

```cpp
str2[i] = ...;
```

Since `str2` is empty, `str2[i]` is always out-of-bounds. This is *undefined behavior*. It might do random things, or it might crash, or it might appear to work.

You probably want to add `str.resize(length);` so that you can write to those indexes.

Comment: Since `str` is passed in by value and is a copy of the original, the asker could also swap the first and last characters and work their way to the middle of `str` swapping as they go. Saves having to make a new `string`.

Comment: @user4581301 better, checking for a palindrome doesn't actually require any swapping at all, so the input string should be passed in by const reference to avoid any copy being made at all.

Comment: Good point. If you've done the work of reversing you could have done the same thing and merely compared the letters as you went.

Answer (score 3):

Mooing has given why this doesn't work. Richard gave the canonical answer in the comment section:

```
return std::equal( str.begin(), str.end(), str.rbegin() );
```

member `rbegin` being the reverse iterator. It is elegant and efficient and end of story.

Comment: Although this does twice the work needed. `std::equal(str.begin(), str.begin() + str.size() / 2, str.rbegin());` does exactly the amount of work needed.

Comment: @Justin Yes, for the palindrome. If the strings tested fails 99% of the time, you needn't worry.